# Swift: Set custom UITableViewCell class inside if statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a Swift newbie and struggling to do something pretty simple.

I want to change the class of a tableViewCell when its tapped. After a lot of Googling I'm now trying to do this by setting a boolean flag (in a dict) and checking the value to determine which class to use.

I've come unstuck with Swift basics of trying to set a variable inside an if statement:

```
// I think I need to instantiate the cell variable here to be used inside 
// and after the if statement but don't know what class type to use.
// I've tried lots of "var cell: xxx = yyy" variations but no luck 

if selectedRows[indexPath.row] == true {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tier3CellExpanded", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tier3CellExpanded
} else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tier3Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tier3TableViewCell
}
let image = UIImage(named: entry.thumbnail)
cell.thumbImageView.image = image
cell.busNameLabel.text = entry.busName
cell.busAddressLabel.text = entry.address
return cell
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Problem is you don't realize the scope of cell. Because you declared it in the if statement it only lives in the if statement. Both of the answers shown will give your cell variable scope through to the return statement

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate that the variable needs to be declared outside the if statement (I tried to point that out in the code comments). But when I do declare the variable outside the if statement I need to specify a type. The variable can have 2 different types depending on the if statement and declaring a variable that is happy to be one of 2 different types is what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just expanding on Charles A. 's answer to show you how to declare cell outside the if statement but still use 2 different cell types.

```
//All shared properities would belong to this class
var cell: MySuperclassCellsInheritFrom
if selectedRows[indexPath.row] {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tier3CellExpanded", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tier3CellExpanded
    if let expandedCell = cell as? Tier3CellExpanded {
        //Set properties specific to Tier3CellExpanded
    }
}
else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tier3Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tier3TableViewCell
    if let regularCell = cell as? Tier3TableViewCell {
       //Set properties specific to Tier3TableViewCell
    }
}

// Configure cell
// Properties that both subclasses share can be set here

return cell
```

This is possible since we declared `cell` as `UITableViewCell` and then cast it after dequeing with identifiers. The cast is possible because the cells you are dequeuing are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`. So after casting you can now set all of that subclasses individual properties.

This method is useful in case there is other code that you want to apply to both cells that you won't need to duplicate in each if statement such as backgroundColor changes or other base `UITableViewCell` properties.

Comment: Will note the classes registered for the identifier must match the class you are casting it to.

Comment: Thanks for this clarity. I tried the code you've written early on in my "poking around in the dark" trying to find the answer (4hrs ago!) but as you'd expect it fails when I try to set a property after the if statement. Being a newbie I don't understand your (& @Ahmad 's) comment above about casting. Would you be able to give me a pointer what I need to do to cast cell given the var could be a couple of different types?

Comment: did you make sure earlier to make cell a `var` and not a `let`?

Comment: Yes, I did :-( It's failing to build in xcode with an error on every line I try to set a property like: `Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'busNameLabel'` All properties I'm trying to set are common to both types and I'm trying to set them after the if statement.

Comment: Best thing is to create another subclass that both these cells inherit from with all shared properties. Then declare cell to that. Updated answer to give you an idea.

Comment: So just to recap. You have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that has all shared properties you want. Then you subclass that class twice with each their own individual properties. Then you set the individual properties in the if statement and the shared properties outside. Kind of a lot of work but it's best practices as far as subclassing goes. Any property that goes into all classes should be in the super class.

Comment: Thanks [comments crossed] - so would that new class inherit from UITableViewCell? So I'm thinking something like this: UITableViewCell -> MySuperclassCellsInheritFrom (set common properties) -> Tier3TableVIewCell (+any unique properties) / Tier3CellExpanded (+any unique properties).  Feels 'efficient' thanks for the top-tips...will give it a go.

Comment: Yep thats the general flow I would go with and have gone with on many occasions.

Comment: Wired it up and it works like a charm...thanks so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112971/discussion-between-james-and-nsgangster).

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this

```
if selectedRows[indexPath.row] == true {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tier3CellExpanded", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tier3CellExpanded
    let image = UIImage(named: entry.thumbnail)
    cell.thumbImageView.image = image
    cell.busNameLabel.text = entry.busName
    cell.busAddressLabel.text = entry.address
    return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tier3Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tier3TableViewCell
    let image = UIImage(named: entry.thumbnail)
    cell.thumbImageView.image = image
    cell.busNameLabel.text = entry.busName
    cell.busAddressLabel.text = entry.address
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this - it feels a bit repetitive but it works :-) There's a lot more config that I stripped out for SO so I'll put that in it's own function to tidy it up.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are declaring a constant in the `if` block and another in the `else` block (that's what the `let` keyword does), so those will go out of scope immediately after you've set them.  Do you have another variable outside your if statement called `cell`?

I would expect the code to look something like:

```
let cell: SomeCellType
if selectedRows[indexPath.row] {
    cell = ...
}
else {
    cell = ...
}

// Configure cell

return cell
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles. The problem I've got (as a complete newbie) is that I don't know what cellType to use in `let cell: SomeCellType` since it has 2 options depending on the result of the if statement.

Comment: the cell should be declared like this var cell:UITableViewCell

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq It depends on if he wants to set properties on some custom class after the `if`/`else` statements, as he does above in his code.  It does not need to be a `var`, though, as he doesn't reassign it after the `if`/`else` statement.

Comment: He can declare it as `UITableViewCell` and then cast it after dequeueing. As long as he uses the right identifier there will be no problem casting it so that he can access the properties of his subclass

Comment: You can do that with the statement (cell as CustomType).property

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq You can, but you can also just declare the cell as that type initially.